# How do I calculate days elapsed since given time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate how many days elapsed from date. When I do `=DAYS(TODAY();C3)` I get 1903-06-04, but I'm expecting number of days.

Comment: Try formatting the cell as a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores dates as a number where the integer portion is the date (starting at 1/1/1900) and the fractional portion is the time. `DAYS()` returns an integer, but if the cell is formatted as a date it will display a (probably very old) date. Changing the cell format to General or Number resolves the issue.